# Symfony2 : error maximum function nesting level of '100' reached aborting symfony

Tags: php, symfony

when I create the first employee, the tables that are linked to him by a relationship no longer appear, and I have these mistakes, I did not understand why he gives these errors,and how to fix it ??

Even i edit the php.ini to xdebug.max_nesting_level = 200 , the same errors appear

here is screenshot:

[image]

when i click ok appear below one:

[image]

Logs :

[image]

Comment: you saw the tow screenshots?

Comment: Just in case: do you restart php-fpm/apache/etc to apply configuration changes?

Comment: yes i restart , and i get the same errors

Comment: post your entity: I'm pretty sure you have linked it with itself or something strange that make your code loop, perhaps, in "fetching" fase.

Comment: yes , i find the error , i wrote $this->$this in the employee entity

Answer (score -1):

it's a problem with Xdebug

open your php.ini and change the xdebug max_nesting_level

```
[xdebug]
xdebug.max_nesting_level = 1000
```

Comment: No, that's not an answer at all. This is a symptom of something else

Comment: Have you any idea ?

Comment: This change is not fixing the issue.